# decorating decorators: try to get my head around understanding it

Tags: python, decorator

I'm trying to understand how to decorate decorators, and wanted to try out the following:

Let's say I have two decorators and apply them to the function `hello()`:

```
def wrap(f):
    def wrapper():
        return " ".join(f())
    return wrapper


def upper(f):
    def uppercase(*args, **kargs):
        a,b = f(*args, **kargs)
        return a.upper(), b.upper()
    return uppercase

@wrap
@upper
def hello():
    return "hello","world"

print(hello())
```

Then I have to start adding other decorators for other functions, but in general the `@wrap` decorator will "wrap all of them"

```
def lower(f):
    def lowercase(*args, **kargs):
        a,b = f(*args, **kargs)
        return a.lower(), b.lower()
    return lowercase

@wrap
@lower
def byebye():
    return "bye", "bye"
```

How do I write a decorator, which decorates my `@lower` and `@upper` decorators?  See below:

```
@wrap
def lower():
    ...

@wrap
def upper():
    ...
```

To achieve the same result as above by only doing:

```
@upper
def hello():
    ...

@lower
def byebye():
    ...
```

Comment: You probably want to read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/739654/understanding-python-decorators. There is an example of decorating decorators at the end, but the answer introduce you slowly to it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here's a generic (and slightly convoluted) solution for decorating decorators with decorators (Yay!).

```
# A second-order decorator
def decdec(inner_dec):
    def ddmain(outer_dec):
        def decwrapper(f):
            wrapped = inner_dec(outer_dec(f))
            def fwrapper(*args, **kwargs):
               return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
            return fwrapper
        return decwrapper
    return ddmain

def wrap(f):
    def wrapper():
        return " ".join(f())
    return wrapper


# Decorate upper (a decorator) with wrap (another decorator)
@decdec(wrap)
def upper(f):
    def uppercase(*args, **kargs):
        a,b = f(*args, **kargs)
        return a.upper(), b.upper()
    return uppercase

@upper
def hello():
    return "hello","world"

print(hello())
```

Comment: This answers the question, almost. You are decorating a decorator, but I wasn't looking for a generic solution, I actually wanted a more simple decorated decorator as somehow my head has to get around the arguments/assignments, no matter how often i go over examples :)

Comment: Well, you can make it non-generic of course. It's even quite simple: write `mywrap = decdec(wrap)` and then use @mywrap as a decorator for decorators.

Answer (score 37):

```
def upper(f):
    @wrap
    def uppercase(*args, **kargs):
        a,b = f(*args, **kargs)
        return a.upper(), b.upper()
    return uppercase
```

---

A decorator in Python

```
 @foo
 def bar(...): ...
```

is just equivalent to

```
 def bar(...): ...
 bar = foo(bar)
```

You want to get the effect of

```
@wrap
@upper
def hello(): ....
```

i.e.

```
hello = wrap(upper(hello))
```

so the `wrap` should be called on the *return value* of `upper`:

```
def upper_with_wrap(f):
   def uppercase(...): ...
   return wrap(uppercase)
```

which is also equivalent to applying the decorator on that function:

```
def upper_with_wrap(f):
   @wrap
   def uppercase(...): ...
   # ^ equivalent to 'uppercase = wrap(uppercase)'
   return uppercase
```

Comment: this is a nice solution, but isn't exactly what I was asking, although maybe I should have stated it more clearly in the question. Although using this technique is cleaner (and easier to understand), I was looking into how to explicitly decorate a decorator. You get my upvote though, wish I could give more, specially for the time taken in explaining your answer :)

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Note that `@wrap` here has nothing to do with the python builtin `@wraps`!

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer from Boaz Yaniv can be simplified a *little* bit like this:

```
def wrap(decorator):                # lowercase/uppercase decorator as argument
    def wrapperA(fn):               # decorated (hello) function as argument
        def wrapperB(*fn_args):     # decorated (hello) functions' arguments as arguments
            # Here, you tell your 'wrap' decorator to get the
            # result that we want to process/wrap further this way:
            t = decorator(fn)(*fn_args)
            return " ".join(t)
        return wrapperB
    return wrapperA


@wrap
def lower(f):
    def lowercase(*args, **kwargs):
        a, b = f(*args, **kwargs)
        return a.lower(), b.lower(), 'in lowercase'
    return lowercase


@wrap
def upper(f):
    def uppercase(*args, **kwargs):
        a, b = f(*args, **kwargs)
        return a.upper(), b.upper(), 'in uppercase'
    return uppercase


@lower
def hello_in_lc():
    return "HELLO", "WORLD"


@upper
def hello_in_uc():
    return "hello", "world"


x = hello_in_lc()
y = hello_in_uc()
print(x)
print(y)
```

Output:

```
hello world in lowercase
HELLO WORLD in uppercase
```

Now, the reason the *wrap* decorator has so much nesting is because once you decorate another decorator's definition, the whole execution process becomes a bit different than the vertical nested decoration. Here's what I am talking about:

```
@wrap        # this wrap decorator is the one provided in the question
@upper
def hello()
    return "Hello", "World"
```

Here's what Python does with the above code. It calls the *wrap* decorator with *upper* function as argument. Inside *wrapper* of *wrap* decorator it finds that the decorator is being invoked. So it invokes it, the *upper* function. Because *upper* itself is a decorator of a function, during its invocation *upper* receives *hello* function as a reference and its arguments are received by wrapper *uppercase*.

Inside *uppercase* a call to *hello* function is made, so *hello* function is then invoked, its result is processed, and is returned back to *wrapper* function in *wrap* decorator which is finally returned back to main module's global scope where hello() was invoked at the bottom.

However, ***decorating a decorator's definition*** is a different story. Take the following code:

```
@wrap        # that's the wrap decorator from my answer
def upper()

@upper
def hello()
```

What's gonna happen here is once you invoke *hello()* the *wrap* decorator would be invoked like in the earlier situation, with *upper* function passed as an argument to *wrap*. However, if you try to invoke *decorator* inside *wrapper* as `decorator()` Python would throw error that *upper* function was called without an argument!

To fix that your wrapper (called *wrapperA* here) in *wrap* decorator needs to receive an argument. This argument is the reference to the function that upper has decorated, which is *hello* function in our case. So the *wrapperA* has to call the *decorator* with hello function (`fn`) as argument.

But executing `decorator(fn)` would give us the reference to *upper* decorator's *uppercase* wrapper. In order to execute it and to pass any argument that *fn* would need we need another wrapper called *wrapperB* nested in *wrapperA*. Here, *wrapper A* would literally act as a decorator of *fn* and its *wrapperB* would take *fn*'s arguments.

So the compounded final call to get the result for any processing on intermediate decorators' (lower and upper) result should look like this:

```
def wrapperB(*fn_args):
    decorator(fn)(*fn_args)

# Alternative
    wrapped_fn = decorator(fn)
    result = wrapped_fn(*fn_args)
```

And that's why so must nesting is needed.

Vertical decorating or the alternative suggested by kennytm [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5952807/4720957) is obviously much better on the eyes.