# Wrapping a decorator, with arguments

Tags: python, flask, marshalling, decorator, flask-restful

I'm trying to replace the `marshal_with` decorator from `flask-restful` with a decorator that does something before calling `marshal_with`. My approach is to try to implement a new decorator that wraps `marshal_with`.

My code looks like:

```
from flask.ext.restful import marshal_with as restful_marshal_with

def marshal_with(fields, envelope=None):
    def wrapper(f):
        print("Do something with fields and envelope")

        @wraps(f)
        def inner(*args, **kwargs):
            restful_marshal_with(f(*args, **kwargs))
        return inner
    return wrapper
```

Unfortunately this seems to break things... no error messages but my API returns a null response when it shouldn't be. Any insights on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You don't `return restful_marshal_with(...)`.

Comment: `restful_marshal_with(f(*args, **kwargs))`. This calls the function f and passes the results to the wrapper. That is different from wrapping it. Try reading : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5952641/decorating-decorators-try-to-get-my-head-around-understanding-it

Comment: @jonrsharpe can you please elaborate? I was following the pattern for decorators with arugments outlined here: http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=240845 but I confess my understanding is incomplete.  How can I preserve the `*args` and `**kwargs**` in the approach you're suggesting?

Comment: Why would adding the `return` *not* preserve them? That's why you're getting a null response, `inner` calls the original function and then calls `restful_marshal_with` with the result, but doesn't return anything.

Comment: @jonrsharpe, thank you, pulling that thread led me to the correct answer.  Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was doing a couple  things wrong here, first, failing to return the output of `restful_marshal_with` as [jonrsharpe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3001761/jonrsharpe) pointed out, secondly, failing to understand a decorator written as a class instead of a function, and how to properly pass values to it.  The correct code ended up being:

```
def marshal_with(fields, envelope=None):
    def wrapper(f):
        print("Do something with fields and envelope")

        @wraps(f)
        def inner(*args, **kwargs):
            rmw = restful_marshal_with(fields, envelope)
            return rmw(f)(*args, **kwargs)
        return inner
    return wrapper
```

As you can see, in addition to not returning `rmw()`, I needed to properly initialize the `request_marshal_with` class before calling it. Finally, it is important to remember that decorators return functions, therefore the arguments of the original function should be passed to the return value of `rmw(f)`, hence the statement `return rmw(f)(*args, **kwargs)`.  This is perhaps more apparent if you take a look at the `flask_restful.marshal_with` code [here](https://github.com/flask-restful/flask-restful/blob/master/flask_restful/__init__.py).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the specifics of `marshal_with`, but it's entirely possible to use multiple decorators on a single function. For instance:

```
def decorator_one(func):
    def inner(*args, **kwargs):
        print("I'm decorator one")
        func(*args, **kwargs)
    return inner

def decorator_two(text):
    def wrapper(func):
        def inner(*args, **kwargs):
            print(text)
            func(*args, **kwargs)
        return inner
    return wrapper

@decorator_one
@decorator_two("I'm decorator two")
def some_function(a, b):
    print(a, b, a+b)


some_function(4, 7)
```

The output this gives is:

```
I'm decorator one
I'm decorator two
4 7 11
```

You can modify this little script by adding print statements after each `inner` function call to see the exact flow control between each decorator as well.

Comment: Thank, you yes, I am familiar with this pattern... the goal is to use a single decorator to accomplish what two could do, since they take the same argument and repeating it is redundant.